# jQuery ajax function always returns an error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a simple jquery ajax call. Everything looks fine in the first place since the parameters are delivered to the controller but the function always returns an error which is not good if I want to update some elements on the page after the desired action is completed. I have seen that there are already a couple of questions on this topic but non of them has helped me so far. Please help if you notice a mistake in the following code. Thx

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#link').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8085/KPIAdmin/kpis/get",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            param1: "value1",
            param2: "value2"
        },
        success: function() {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
    });
});

});
```

On the server side

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public void ajaxGetKPI(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {

    System.out.println("param1: " + param1);
    System.out.println("param2: " + param2);
}
```

Error log

```
Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 11 weitere… } ajaxGetKPI.js:24
"error" ajaxGetKPI.js:25
"Not Found"
```

Comment: I have added `dataType: 'json'` right below `type: "GET"` but unfortunatelly it did not solved my problem

Comment: I think the problem is the server/service, not the Ajax request. Have you tried to do the GET in the browser?

Comment: You're right! Thx the problem was on the server side. `ajaxGetKPI()` method must return somethig or more precisely a string name of a web page which will be rendered by view resolver since it does not return any data or json. As soon as I added `return "redirect:/kpis";` everything was fine. `dataType: 'json'` is not neccessary in the ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a controller declares a void return type, Spring will infer the view name. In your case it will search the view name `get`, hence the `Not found error`.

You can annotate your controller with `@ResponseBody` than the response will be returned inside the body, but since the body will be empty a better option is to retrun a `ResponseEntity` something like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public  ResponseEntity<String> void ajaxGetKPI(@RequestParam("param1") String param1, @RequestParam("param2") String param2) {
    System.out.println("param1: " + param1);
    System.out.println("param2: " + param2);
    new ResponseEntity<String>("OK",HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

Comment: Exactly! As soon as I have executed the GET in the browser I have noticed the same. Thx